# Do the following sets span $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Could somebody please confirm, if I have done this right or whether my approach is right?

Consider a $\mathbb{R}$ -Vectorspace $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ of real polynomials: 
$a_{0}+a_{1} X+a_{2} X^{2}$ 
of degree $\leq 2 .$ Which of the following sets spans $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})?$
1) $1, X, X^{2}$ . 
2) $1, X, X^{2}-1$ 
3) $1-X, X-X^{2}, X^{2}-1$ 
4) $1, X^{2}-X$

---

1)  $\operatorname{span}\left(1, x, x^{2}\right)=\left\{\alpha+\beta x+\gamma x^{2} | \alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \mathbb{R}\right\} \in P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ 
Clearly spans if we choose $\alpha=a_{0}, \beta=a_{1}, \gamma=a_{2}$

2) $\operatorname{span}\left(1, x, x^{2}-1\right)=\left[\alpha+\beta x+\gamma\left(x^{2}-1\right)\right\}= 
\left\{(\alpha-\gamma)+\beta x+\gamma x^{2}\right\} $ 
We then see, if we choose $\beta=a_{1}$,$\gamma=a_{2}$,$\alpha=a_{0}+\gamma=a_{0}+a_{2}$ 
The set spans $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$

3) $\operatorname{span}\left(1-x, x-x^2, x^{2}-1\right)=\left\{\alpha(1-x)+\beta\left(x-x^{2}\right)+\gamma\left(x^{2}-1\right)\right\}=\left\{(\alpha-\gamma)+(B-\alpha) x+(\gamma-\beta) x^{2}\right\}$ 
If there is a solution to the following equations, it will span P3:
$(\alpha-\gamma)=a_{0}$
$(\beta-\alpha)=a_{1}=>(-\alpha+B)=a_{1}$
$(\gamma-\beta)=a_{2} \Rightarrow(-\beta+\gamma)=a_{2}$

Solving the system of equations;
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}{1} & {0} & {-1} & {a_{1}} \\ {-1} & {1} & {0} & {a_{2}} \\ {0} & {-1} & {1} & {a_{3}}\end{array}\right) \sim \left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}{1} & {0} & {-1} & {a_{1}} \\ {0} & {1} & {-1} & {a_{2}+a_{1}} \\ {0} & {-1} & {1} & {a_{3}}\end{array}\right) \sim \left( \begin{array}{ccc|c}{1} & {0} & {-1} & {a_{1}} \\ {0} & {1} & {-1} & {a_{2}+a_{1}} \\ {0} & {0} & {0} & {a_{3}+a_{2}+a_{3}}\end{array}\right)$
Gives us no solution. Which means, we can't choose $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, so that the set spans $P_{3}(\mathbb{R})$.

4) $\operatorname{span}\left(1, x^{2}-x\right)=\left\{\alpha+\beta\left(x^{2}-x\right)\right\}=\left\{\alpha-\beta x+\beta x^{2}\right\}$ 
We can't choose $\beta=-a_1$ and $\beta=a_2$. 
There is no solution and therefore it doesn't span P3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the correct answers, but you could’ve arrived at them with less work.

That (2) is a spanning set follows directly from (1) being a linearly-independent spanning set, i.e., a basis: if $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis for a space, then so is $\{v_1,v_2,v_1-v_3\}$.

(4) Cannot span the space since we know from (1) that it is three-dimensional.

For (3), notice that $X^2-1=-(1-X)-(X-X^2)$, so the third vector is redundant. This case therefore reduces to the same situation as (4): you don’t have enough vectors to span the space.

Comment: Thanks. I completely forgot, that I could check whether the set of elements was linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

(a) and (b) You are right for the right reasons.

(c) It is much easier to see that $1$ is a root of all those polynomials. Therefore, $1$ is a root of each polynomial from their span.

(d) No two vectors span a $3$-dimensional vector space.

Answer (score 0):

This looks all good. For an even faster solution to 4), note that only two polynomials have been given but $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ has dimension $3$, and so you cannot span it.